# how to add a view in uinavcontroller which is displaying as a modal

Tags: objective-c, ios

My view contains a signup button which display signup view modally, I want this signup inside uinavigationcontroller, how can I add this view inside uinavcontroller.

Comment: The problem is not very clear. Any `UIViewController` can be added to navigation stack by `pushViewController:animated`. If you just need a navigation bar for your modal view controller, then just wrap your `UIViewController` within `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Using `[self.view addSubview:signupView]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have your button's action method present the navigation controller like this:

```
-(IBAction)showSignup:(id)sender {
    MyViewController *signupController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    //Other setup for signupController;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:signupController];

    //Set modal presentation and transition styles, if needed.

    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```